# Why can't I find a certain text on my site in Google?

Tags: seo, google, search-engines, googlebot

I can't find certain text on my site in Google, even if I'm searching specifically on the page that this text in on:

```
site:mysite.com/page.html hidden text
```

I tried searching just for "site:mysite.com/page.html" - this page is indexed by Google, but the bot doesn't see all the text.

I went to Google Webmaster Tools - Fetch as Google. Downloaded HTTP response of the page clearly shows that the hidden text is loaded.
What could be the source of this problem, why isn't a certain text on the page not seen by Google?

P.S. The page is 1.6MB and it didn't load to the end, maybe this is the problem?

Comment: How is this text "hidden"? Is it already hidden by CSS as the page loads? Is it hidden by JS _after_ the page loads? Is it "visible", but layered behind another element (and so is "hidden")? How does the user display the hidden text? Click event? Scroll of the page? Is there a crawlable "permalink" that will display this "hidden text"?

Answer (score 4):

It appears Google is no longer indexing any content that is hidden under read more panels that are hidden during the `onLoad` event.

Last year, Google acknowledged render your full page as a normal user would and this is probably the case here. If Google is seeing what the user sees, then they will index that content.

[read more here](https://www.seroundtable.com/google-index-click-to-expand-19449.html). Some users noticed that Google is no longer indexing and ranking such hidden content.

Answer (score -1):

I think Google is not indexing your sites. So please  go again through article and  title  tag, meta tag, meta description,keyword stuffing,Anchor tag, Alt text and keyword density. Also update your site map, If you have or install site  map.