# Why is hidden content not always indexed?

Tags: seo, javascript, googlebot, search-engine-indexing, hidden-text

I've read several blogs discussing the 'hidden content' issue. [This article](http://www.returnondigital.com/blog/does-hiddentabbed-content-still-get-picked-up-by-google) experimented with several options. It concludes that Google DOES index hidden content.

The issues is [also discussed here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/87418/why-cant-i-find-a-certain-text-on-my-site-in-google/87419#87419).

However when I use "site: (my hidden content)" I do not always see my content indexed. The content is hidden with JavaScript: `js_readmore_handle` and `js_readmore_content`.

Can anyone explain why hidden content is not always indexed?

Answer (score 1):

This question was answered by the person who asked it in a comment:

> Well I found the answer after some research. Google states that hidden content on your page is probably not critical for that particular page. This includes click to expand content. If you want this content indexed you should make sure it's visible for users when they land at that page. Since Google assumes that users not always see the hidden content Google prevents the content from being indexed